# Access one Java class from another Java class in Javafx

Tags: java, graph, charts, javafx

I am unable to call a class from another class in my javafx application.
I make a pie-graph in java. When called individually this runs
successfully. But when I use this code through access from another class from this current class using this code

```
Graph main = new Graph();
Application.launch();
```

it is not working.

And this is the graph code being called from the above, sitting in its own class.

```
package semi_final1;
//package Graph;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Graph extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Analysis");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
      ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Levels", 13),
                new PieChart.Data("Points", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("Questions", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Answers", 22),
                new PieChart.Data("Length of Contents", 20),
                 new PieChart.Data("Likes", 20),
                new PieChart.Data("Dislikes", 10),
                 new PieChart.Data("Jaccard", 10));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: netbeans isn't the issue, it is about how to do things in javafx, so changed title. Straightened out some of the narrative to more easily describe inter-class calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Application.launch(String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) only works, if called from a class that extends application (and that class will be used as the `Application`'s class). If you want to start a javafx application from a different class, you need to use the [`Application.launch(Class, String...`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) method:

```
Application.launch(Graph.class);
```

Note that you must not start more than 1 `Application` from the same program.

(Move the code of the scene graph, ect. to different classes if you're planning to do this; e.g. using fxml+controller would be a good idea in that case)

Comment: But How to pass argument in this.For example some int value i want to pass form this class to graph classs. How I will.@fabian

Comment: If I use this GrahP Code in same class.How it will be.Means current Class I Extend with frame.and this Graph class extend from Application Class.How I extend Both class in same place.How this work.

Comment: @NafeesAhmed: What do you mean with "frame"? If refer to using fxml+controller: You would create the controller as a **different** class, which would allow you to use it independent from your application class. Any data transfer between application class and the ui would be done by using methods of the controller.